# Render partial view with json object coming from a web api call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

**Introduction**

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 5` and `WebApi 2.0` in one of my current projects.
Using ajax calls I get the needed information out of my database using a function like:

```
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {

    /*---------------------------------------------------
        Users Web Api javascript
    ---------------------------------------------------*/

    UsersApiScript = function () {
        var uri;
    }

    $.extend(UsersApiScript, {
        init: function() {

            // ### Assign the root url for calling the web api controllers
            uri = 'api/usersapi';

            // ### Assign event handlers to the elements ###

            // Add click event to open user details
            $('.user-details').click(UsersApiScript.loadItem);

        },
        loadItem: function () {
            var $a = $(this);
            var id = $a.attr('data-id');

            $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id)
                .done(function (data) {
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));

                    // Get the partial view to show in modal
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache: false,
                        url: uri_internal + '/getuserdetails',
                        done: function (result) {
                            console.log(result);
                            $('#content').after(result);
                        },
                        fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                            console.log('Error: ' + err);
                        }
                    });
                })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + err);
                });
        }
    });
}(window, document, jQuery));
```

This is working fine, I get the information in json format.

**Question**

Now I would like to show a bootstrap modal to display the information.
Like others projects I use `partial views` to display the data, but then you had a `Modal` which was defined and passed using the controller to your partial view.

Now using the Web Api you have a json object that I need to pass to my partial view.

Consider following implementation:

*Controller*

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetUserDetails(User user)
    {
        return PartialView(user);
    }
}
```

*Partial View*

```
@model ProsecMdmHelper.Models.User

<div class="modal fade" id="modalUserDetails" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalUserDetailsLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalUserDetailsLabel"><i class="icon-check"></i>Gebruiker details</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <p>User is called @Model.Name</p>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Questions**

- How do I pass my Web Api json result data to my partial view?
- How do I display this view to the user?
- Can you define this json object `User` into this partial view to do something like `@Modal.Username` ?

**UPDATE**

Ok I already get the modal html code back from the server but it won't get added to my document after the `#content` tag. Async issue?

Comment: how about making one more `ajax` call to `partiaview` once you get `json` data and pass that data to the method which you call to get `partialview`?

Comment: How do you do this? If you call the partial view using ajax to display the html?

Comment: You call `ActionResult` and return `partialview` and `load` the result in `modal`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Can you view my update, I got everything working except adding the html from my server to my document

Comment: Ok.. sorry for this but I would suggest you to use `.load` instead of `ajax` after getting back the `json` and pass the data in the `load` like `$('#content').load(uri_internal + '/getuserdetails', { data: data },function(){  })`

Comment: Ok but I want to load this content directly after the `#content` element not inside is that possible? Because now it removes the existing content

Comment: Then create a `div` after `#content` and load the same in that!!